# How do i get a variable from a function?

Tags: python-3.x

So I am a total noob at python so im sorry if im not being specific enough.

I am writing a tic tac toe program and the hardest thing is getting to switch turns

so i wrote a function to do this but i cant get the "turn" variable which belongs to another function. Im sorry if im being moronic but this is the best i can explain it. Thanks for your Time :)

BTW here is the code

```
x="X"
o="O"
EMPTY=" "
TIE="TIE"
NUM_SQUARES=9

def display_instruct():
    print(
    """
    Welcome to the greatest challenge ever

    Tic
    Tac 
    Toe

    the board is as shown

    0|1|2
    ------
    3|4|5
    -----
    6|7|8


    Prepare as teh game is about to start
    """)

def yesno(question):
    response=None
    while response not in ("y","n"):
        response=input(question).lower()
    return response
def asknum(question, low, high):
    response=None
    while response not in range(low,high):
        response=int(input(question))
    return response

def pieces():
    go_first=yesno("Do you want the first move")

    if go_first=="y":
        print("then take the first move you will need it")
        human=x
        computer=o
        turn=x
        return computer, human
    else:
        print ("Ok i shall go first")
        computer=x
        human=o
        turn=x
        return computer, human



def new_board():
    board=[]
    for square in range(NUM_SQUARES):
        board.append(EMPTY)
    return board

def display_board(board):
    print ("\n")
    print (board[0],"|",board[1],"|",board[2])
    print ("----------")
    print (board[3],"|",board[4],"|",board[5])
    print ("----------")
    print (board[6],"|",board[7],"|",board[8])

def legal_moves(board):
    moves=[]
    for square in range(NUM_SQUARES):
        if board[square]==EMPTY:
            moves.append(square)
    return moves

def winner(board):
    WAYS_TO_WIN=((0,1,2),(3,4,5),(6,7,8),(0,3,6),(1,4,7),(2,5,8),(0,4,8),(2,4,6))

    for row in WAYS_TO_WIN:
        if board[row[0]]==board[row[1]]==board[row[2]]!=EMPTY:
            winner=[row[0]]
            return winner
        if EMPTY not in board:
            return TIE
        return None



def human_move(board,human):
    legal=legal_moves(board)
    move=None
    print (legal)
    while move not in legal:
        move=asknum("Where will you move",0,NUM_SQUARES)
    return move

def computer_move(board,computer,human):
    board=board[:]
    BEST_MOVES=(4,0,2,6,8,1,3,5,7)
    print ("I shall take square number", end=" ")
    for move in legal_moves(board):
        board[move]=computer
        if winner(board)==computer:
            print(move)
            return move
    for move in legal_moves(board):
        board[move]=human
        if winner(board)==human:
            print(move)
        return move

    board[move]=EMPTY

    for move in BEST_MOVES:
        if move in legal_moves(board):
            print (move)
        return move

def next_turn(turn):
    if turn==x:
        return o
    else:
        return x
def congrat_winner(the_winner,computer,human):
    if the_winner!=TIE:
        print(the_winner, "WON")
    else:
        print ("Its a ttie")
    if the_winner==computer:
        print ("I WON HA HA IN YO FACE")
    elif the_winner==human:
        print ("NO IT CANNOT BE")
    elif the_winner==TIE:
        print ("you were lucky this time")
def curturn(turn,computer,human):

    if turn==x and move!="" and move!=" ":
        turn=o
    elif turn==o and move!="" and move!=" ":
        turn=x


def main():
    display_instruct()

    computer, human=pieces()
    turn=x
    board=new_board()
    display_board(board)
    curturn(turn,computer,human)
    while not winner (board):
        display_board(board)


        if turn == human:
            move=human_move(board,human)
            board[move]=human   
        else:
             move=computer_move(board,computer,human)
             board[move]=computer
             display_board(board)
             turn=next_turn(turn)
             the_winner=winner(board)
             congrat_winner(the_winner,computer,human)




main()
```

Comment: Where do you want the `turn` variable but can't get it? Please clarify your actual question, and maybe only show the code which has a problem

Comment: Im sorry for this, i want it within the function curturn Thanks :)

Comment: To me it isn't really clear what you're asking - you already pass the turn variable into the curturn function, so what's the problem?

Comment: Oops forgot to delete that before posting, that was passing the function into the function, if you compile the program and then you enter "y" when it asks you if you want the first move you will get an error "global name 'move' is not defined"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions look like this (simplified):

```
def functionname(parameter1, parameter2=foo):
    code that does stuff
    return value
```

If you in your function want to access a variable from the calling function, you pass it in as a parameter. If you from the calling function want to access a variable from the function you call, you return it.

You can also use global variable (which you do, I see) and that is a Bad Idea, as it will make your program messy and hard to debug. So avoid that if you can (although in a small program like this, it's not a disaster, so don't bother now).

If you want to access variables from completely different places, you probably want to look into object-oriented programming, with classes and stuff.